# Pandas - Filter Dataframe on Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df:

```
type    rec_1   rec_2   rec_3   rec_4   rec_1_outlier   rec_2_outlier   rec_3_outlier   rec_4_outlier
yellow  1          7       3       1       FALSE        TRUE                  TRUE          TRUE
red     3         11       2       5       FALSE        TRUE                 FALSE          FALSE
blue    5         2        1       6        TRUE        FALSE                FALSE          FALSE
green   2         9       13       9        FALSE       FALSE                TRUE           FALSE
```

I want to get separate dataframes per type where the _outlier columns are only false, but the rec columns are independent of each other and one column may be true and the other false.

So theoretically if I were to try

```
df_blue = df['type']=='blue' & df['rec_1_outlier']=='False' & df['rec_2_outlier']=='False' & df['rec_3_outlier']=='False' & df['rec_4_outlier']=='False'
```

This would might never select any rows because the _outlier columns might never all be false.

I have also thought about doing it one column at a time like this.

```
df_blue_rec_1 = df['type']=='blue' & df['rec_1_outlier']=='False'
df_blue_rec_2 = df['type']=='blue' & df['rec_2_outlier']=='False'
```

Then just appending the separate dataframes into one.

I have this feeling like there is a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path. What you did was create a boolean mask. like so:

```
mask_blue =((df['type']=='blue') & 
            (df['rec_1_outlier']=='False') & 
            (df['rec_2_outlier']=='False') & 
            (df['rec_3_outlier']=='False') & 
            (df['rec_4_outlier']=='False')
```

This mask gives a list of true/false that corresponds to the indexes of your original df.

```
df_blue = df.loc[mask_blue,:]
```

Now you choose which column to transfer to df_blue by changing the (:) above. for example:

```
df_blue = df.loc[mask_blue,['type','rec_1']]
```

This would give a df with the column: `type` and `rec_1`

**Update**
To do this for every individual rec_1, try creating on mask for each rec_x. This will give nan values for True outliers. The following code is an example for rec_1 and rec_2.

```
df_blue = pd.Datafram()
mask_blue1 =((df['type']=='blue') & (df['rec_1_outlier']=='False'))
df_blue.loc[:,'rec_1'] = df.loc[mask_blue1,'rec_1']
mask_blue2 =((df['type']=='blue') & (df['rec_2_outlier']=='False'))
df_blue.loc[:,'rec_2'] = df.loc[mask_blue2,'rec_2']
```

Comment: Thanks Kosmos. Question for you, would your mask above only find rows where all the _outlier columns = False? Sometimes the row would have rec_1_outlier == False but rec_2_outlier == True. In that row I would want to take the value for rec_1_outlier but reject rec_2_outlier. Does that make sense?

Comment: No problem. Hope it works for you. I've updated the post to match your question. This solution will give nan values when the mask gives False.